# Android:Not receiving any response from Socket.IO

Tags: android, socket.io-1.0

I am writing a simple code to connect to Socket.Io server.

Simply I am connecting to Socket.io in onCreate and pushing some message after button click. But unfortuantely not receiving asingle response from there. My debug point in not comming inside **Emitter.Listener**. I am doing my code as below:

```
public class MainChatPage extends Activity{

private Socket mSocket;
private EditText mInputMessageView;
private Button send;
private GlobalSharedPreference prefs;
private APIInterface apiInterface;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constantstuffs.SERVER_URL);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_main_chat_page);
    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    prefs = new GlobalSharedPreference(this);
    mInputMessageView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessege);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptSend();
        }
    });


    mSocket.connect();
    mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
}


private void attemptSend() {
    String message = mInputMessageView.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        return;
    }

    mInputMessageView.setText("");
    mSocket.emit("new message", createJson(message));
}

private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {


    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                Log.v("some response", ""+data);
            }
        });
    }
};
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.off("new message", onNewMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to listen on `EVENT_ERROR` to be check whether there is an error during the connection?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to implement EVENT_ERROR code here..Any sample code will be appreciable

Comment: it should be something like this
https://pastebin.com/SR0u8DBF

Comment: No, not a single event is responding after emit message. I am using gradle 0.3.0 i.e `compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'`  ..is this right ?

Comment: Here its connecting always in onConnect method properly..but not any response in any of the event.

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java ?

Comment: You wil have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Clearly visible in the logcat. And your app should crash.

Comment: No not crashing..Its connecting but not responding ..btw where I have to use back ground thread ..is it when sending data in sendMessage or for listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in `application`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

For more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic